# Why is this automatic select first option jquery script not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a list where I have implemented the cascading dropdown feature from http://spservices.codeplex.com/. It is working fine, however I want to automatically select the first option in the last dropdown box.
The code below works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in Internet Explorer (IE6/7/8/9). 
Does anyone know why?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../../../Hidden/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../../../Hidden/jquery.SPServices-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Departments",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Unit",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "CodeDesc",
        parentColumn: "Unit",
        childColumn: "Department"
    });

    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Departments",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "CodeDesc",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Department",
        childColumn: "DeptCode",
        completefunc: function () { $("select[title=DeptCode]").children().eq(1).attr("selected", "selected"); }
    });  



});
```

Markup:

```
<tr><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Department<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr></H3></td><td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"><span dir="none"><span style="vertical-align:middle"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_6f0051d2_c213_41cd_aa16_6fadb40281aa$ff5_1$ctl00$ctl01" type="text" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6f0051d2_c213_41cd_aa16_6fadb40281aa_ff5_1_ctl00_ctl01" class="ms-lookuptypeintextbox" onfocusout="HandleLoseFocus()" opt="_Select" title="Department" optHid="SPDepartment_Hiddenctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_6f0051d2_c213_41cd_aa16_6fadb40281aa$ff5_1$ctl00" onkeypress="HandleChar()" onkeydown="HandleKey()" match="" choices="2231011D|1|2231022D|2|2231033D|3|2231033I|4|2232011D|5|2232011I|6|2232022D|7|2232044D|8|2232044I|9|2233011I|10|2233022I|11|2233044I|12|2234011D|13|2234011I|14|2234022D|15|2234022I|16|2234033D|17|2235011D|18|2235011I|19|2236011D|20|2236011I|21|2236022D|22|2236022I|23|2236033I|24|2242401I|25|2242502I|26|2244001I|27|2245001D|28|2245001I|29|2245500I|30|2246027D|31|2246027I|32|2246029D|33|2246029I|34|2246120D|35|2246125D|36|2246125I|37|2246130D|38|2246130I|39|2246254D|40|2246254I|41|2246255I|42|2246346D|43|2246346I|44|2246362D|45|2246362I|46|2246436D|47|2246436I|48|2246440D|49|2246440I|50|2246441D|51|2246801I|52|2249201I|53|2249902D|54" onchange="HandleChange()" /><img alt="Display lookup values" onclick="ShowDropdown('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6f0051d2_c213_41cd_aa16_6fadb40281aa_ff5_1_ctl00_ctl01');" src="/_layouts/images/dropdown.gif" style="border-width:0px;vertical-align:middle;" /></span><br/></span></td></tr>
<tr><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>DeptCode</nobr></H3></td><td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"><span dir="none"><span style="vertical-align:middle"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_6f0051d2_c213_41cd_aa16_6fadb40281aa$ff6_1$ctl00$ctl01" type="text" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6f0051d2_c213_41cd_aa16_6fadb40281aa_ff6_1_ctl00_ctl01" class="ms-lookuptypeintextbox" onfocusout="HandleLoseFocus()" opt="_Select" title="DeptCode" optHid="SPDeptCode_Hiddenctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_6f0051d2_c213_41cd_aa16_6fadb40281aa$ff6_1$ctl00" onkeypress="HandleChar()" onkeydown="HandleKey()" match="" choices="(None)|0|2231011D|1|2231022D|2|2231033D|3|2231033I|4|2232011D|5|2232011I|6|2232022D|7|2232044D|8|2232044I|9|2233011I|10|2233022I|11|2233044I|12|2234011D|13|2234011I|14|2234022D|15|2234022I|16|2234033D|17|2235011D|18|2235011I|19|2236011D|20|2236011I|21|2236022D|22|2236022I|23|2236033I|24|2242401I|25|2242502I|26|2244001I|27|2245001D|28|2245001I|29|2245500I|30|2246027D|31|2246027I|32|2246029D|33|2246029I|34|2246120D|35|2246125D|36|2246125I|37|2246130D|38|2246130I|39|2246254D|40|2246254I|41|2246255I|42|2246346D|43|2246346I|44|2246362D|45|2246362I|46|2246436D|47|2246436I|48|2246440D|49|2246440I|50|2246441D|51|2246801I|52|2249201I|53|2249902D|54" onchange="HandleChange()" /><img alt="Display lookup values" onclick="ShowDropdown('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6f0051d2_c213_41cd_aa16_6fadb40281aa_ff6_1_ctl00_ctl01');" src="/_layouts/images/dropdown.gif" style="border-width:0px;vertical-align:middle;" /></span><br/></span></td></tr>
```

Thanks,
David

Comment: Please post all the relevant code and markup in order for someone to help you. That small function snippet is not enough. Please also list the version numbers of the browsers if your question is related to a specific browser.

Comment: No code so I'll guess : shouldn't you use `.children().eq(0)` rather than `.children().eq(1)` ?

Comment: Apologies JackWilson, I have added the requested information that should have been included from the first post.

Comment: Sylvain Thrd, no that would pick the blank value. I did still try this and others.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about Sharepoint but judging by the markup you posted, it looks like it generates additional markup using Javascript. Perhaps it's a case of the DOM element not being accessible at the time that you're trying to set it? Since it's inconsistent across browsers it's unlikely to be a problem with the actual jQuery code or markup.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("select[title=DeptCode] option:first").attr("selected",true);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying but that didnt work in any browser for me.

Comment: `.attr("selected", true")` -> `.attr("selected", "selected")`, since the selected attribute either takes `selected` as a value or is disabled.

Comment: $("select[title=DeptCode] option:first").attr("selected", "selected"); does not work in any browser for me.